# Cricket Audio. While playing many CkSound effects, best to call destroy CkSound?

Tags: android, c++, audio, iso

Using the [Cricket Audio Sound Engine](http://crickettechnology.com)  ( ios & android) how would I set up a machine gun type sound effect. I need to be able to play many instances of a sound per second. The sound effects need to layer on top of each other.

My solution is to create a new [CkSound](http://www.crickettechnology.com/doc/Cricket.html) instance and forget about it. I don't see a easy to destroy the sound, with out a complex sound tracking method. Will this cause memory problems as I am creating thousands of CkSounds over the course of a play session? I really don't want to have to keep track of individual sounds for garbage collection.

```
// Example sound effect call
void SoundManager::playEffect(const char* name){
    // I make a sound , play it , and forget about it
    sound = CkSound::newBankSound(g_bank, name);
    sound->play();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don’t recommend you create instances and don’t destroy them, as this is a memory leak, so your app will use more and more memory as time goes on.

You could try something like this…

to initialize:

```
const int k_maxSounds = 5; // maximum number of sound instances to be playing at once
CkSound* g_sounds[k_maxSounds];
for (int i = 0; i < k_maxSounds; ++i)
{
   g_sounds[i] = CkSound::newBankSound(g_bank, name);
}
```

to play another sound instance, find the first available instance and play it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k_maxSounds; ++i)
{
   if (!g_sounds[i]->isPlaying())
   {
      g_sounds[i]->play();
      break;
   }
}
```

-steve -*Cricket Audio Creator answered via email*